# How to install Ubuntu from zipped files

Tags: system-installation

I just downloaded Ubuntu and have a huge pack of zipped files. What should I do to actually install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

The iso is not a zip file. Windows (mis) identifies it as a zip if you do not have any CD burning software installed.

You take the iso and either burn it to a DVD or more modern use a flash / usb drive.

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall